# NodeJS os.networkInterfaces() returns [Object object] in Browserify bundle

Tags: node.js, browserify

I am a beginner to Browserify for NodeJS and I wrote a simple module that would list the network interfaces and return it to the person viewing a webpage. I begun by writing the main.js file,

```
var os = require("os");
document.write(os.networkInterfaces());
```

Then I compiled the code via this command *browserify main.js -o bundle.js* which on completion didn't yield any output but resulted in the creation of bundle.js. This is when the html code comes into play,

```
<html>
    <body>
        Hi, here are your network interfaces:
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Upon loading the page it says, **Hi, here are your network interfaces:[object Object]** when I was expecting a string that NodeJS says it's os.networkInterfaces() function returns when called. What did I  do wrong and how can I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has nothing to do with `browserify`.
`document.write` tries to stringify an object by calling the `Object#toString()` function of that object's prototype.

So, if you want to print a string use `JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)` (2 is for 2 spaces, for prettification)

```
var os = require("os");
document.write(JSON.stringify(os.networkInterfaces(), null, 2)));
```

Note: you can check in console by typing:

```
console.log({"foo":"bar"}.toString());
```

Also, you need to use [`os-browserify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/os-browserify) if you want to use `os` module in browsers

Comment: When I run your first example the webpage renders {} as the result of present interfaces but when I run the code natively in node with console.log and without JSON.Stringify it yields an actual result.

Comment: Yes,  because os module is not availble for browsers. you need to use `os-browserify` for that. check edited anaswer.